# Swift JavascriptCore Node.js Stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, swift, macos, cocoa

I've recently read about how to use [NPM packages in Swift](http://www.thesmythgroup.com/in-development/how-to-use-npm-packages-in-native-ios-apps/). There is an NPM package that creates a Node.js Stream.

In Node.js I can just do the following to pipe that stream to the filesystem and create a file from it.

```
const fs = require('fs');

myStream(myDetails).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('test.txt'));
```

Is there anyway to do this in Swift using JavascriptCore?

Basically I want to take that stream and write it to the file system using Swift/Cocoa.

Can I maybe convert the stream into something else and pass that into Swift or something?

Comment: You can use a userland implementation of streams in `streams2`. I would then try to google for something in the ways of "javascriptcore fs integration", but streaming will be tricky if that's not easily supported...

Anyway: +1 and a * from me - I'd happily port my streaming module to JSC.